# AWS - Elastic Beanstalk/Glassfish index.html file

Tags: amazon-web-services, glassfish, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Amazon's AWS Elastic Beanstalk to deploy my web application. I am having a problem where the deployed application will display a "Your server is now running" page, rather than my own index.html/jsp page. What I am really confused about is that this appears to happen at random - sometimes my deployment will work fine, but others I will get this page.

[image]

Is there a specific configuration or directory structure I need to use in order to make my index.html the default? I had previously had my project configured for Tomcat, and am using a regular .war file directory structure.

Any help is appreciated